# Regarding use of a query

Tags: sql

I am solving few sql queries myself,

in a question , which says

> Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area:

```
SELECT continent, name, area
 FROM world x 
  WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT area FROM world y
        WHERE y.continent=x.continent
          AND area>0)
```

I don't understand what does he mean by world x and world y ? could anyone please explain that?

Comment: It's a correlated subquery, the x and y are aliasing the table being used, aliases are helpful in general, but necessary when referencing the same table twice within a query.

Comment: @GoatCO...beat me to it again lol...my comment nemesis!! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x and y are aliases. it allows you to identify the table in "WHERE y.continent=x.continent"

Comment: Does the x contain three columns: continent, name, area while y contains just one column: area? Also, what does y.continent mean? I am quite confused of this notation.

Answer (score 0):

x and y are used as aliases (a short alternative name for reference purposes) of the table. This allows the use of the world table in two different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

x and y are just aliases that are used to qualify the columns: if you had aliases and used the  same table twice, it is not clear to which table instance a column belongs.

In your case, you are matching two instances of the same table on a column - `continent` - and the aliases are used to make it clear to the sql engine what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

That is aliasing the table name, commonly written as:

```
FROM `table` AS `t`
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` and `y` are [table aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You use them to make the query more concise/readable and/or to use a query which selects the same table multiple times like here.

In  SQL-Server 2005 and later you can use this query to get the desired result:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT continent, name, area,
           rank=dense_rank() over(Partition By x.continent Order By area Desc)
    From world 
)
SELECT continent, name, area FROM CTE WHERE rank = 1
```

[`DENSE_RANK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)  might return multiple countries per continent if they have the same largest area. If you just want one replace `DENSE_RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: you mean we are speaking to two identical tables but just naming them differently? Am I getting this right? If so, why do it at all?

Answer (score -2):

The above example is known as a correlated or synchronized sub-query.
It would say “select the country details from world where the population is greater than or equal to the population of all countries where the continent is the same”

Comment: you are not answering the question, it was about the Variables x and y. The Query was about the largest country in a continent which was written in the question already.